# Why atos command gives the same hex number entered

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I have used

```
atos -arch armv7 -o myappname 0x6ce59f84
```

It gives 0x6ce59f84 as the result. I followed the instructions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949

Why this display as the number i have entered.

Comment: Has your release binary been stripped of symbols?

Comment: I am new for iOS dev. I dont know whether, i have enabled it or not. How can i confirm about that from a released binary.

Comment: If you have to ask, then it is true.  The default behavior of a release build is to remove this information so other cannot see it.

Comment: These are the settings i have set. -Strip debug Symbols During Copy
  -Debug   -NO                                                     -Release   -Yes